# Why can't I use the var mSelectedItem in inner class ViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-adapter

I define mSelectedItem as a public var in the class CustomAdapter, I think  `mSelectedItem=getAdapterPosition()`  will be Ok when I use mSelectedItem in inner class ViewHolder.

But it failed, and display "Unresolved reference: mSelectedItem" error, why?

And more, what is good way for `getAdapterPosition()` in Kotlin, there is hint which display "This inspection reports calls to java get and set methods that can be replaced with use of Kotlin synthetic properties", but it will cause errro when I use  `mSelectedItem=getAdapterPosition` .

```
class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    public var mSelectedItem = -1


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
        holder.itemView.radioButton.setChecked(position == mSelectedItem);
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return backupItemList.size
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {               

            itemView.radioButton.tag=aMSetting._id
            itemView.textViewUsername.text=aMSetting.createdDate.toString()
            itemView.textViewAddress.text=aMSetting.description
            mSelectedItem=getAdapterPosition()  //It will cause error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's not `inner class ViewHolder`.

Comment: Thanks, how can I fixed it?

Comment: But ViewHolder is packaged by CustomAdapter, why isn't it inner class?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html

Comment: It's just `class`. It's not `inner class`. Specify it as `inner class` and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to make the ViewHolder an `inner class` (which you should not), you could create a class like AdapterSelection that has a field `var selectedItem:Int` inside it and replace your `public var mSelectedItem = -1` with `private var mSelectedItem = AdapterSelection(-1`). Then pass the `mSelectedItem` to the `bind` method (`bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting, adapterSelection:AdapterSelection)` and inside the bind, set the position `adapterSelection.selectedItem = getAdapterPosition()`.

You could have passed the adapter itself, but it is messy, that's why I suggest making another class.

Answer (score 0):

ViewHolder is the Recycler rather than the operator.if you want to get the position,you put this `mSelectedItem = position` in onBindViewHolder.And this method named getAdapterPosition() always works on with notifyItemsetChanged().hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! but position is obsolete